# Duplicates in accessing address book

Tags: swift

For some reason, I keep getting duplicates on a lot of the contacts that I'm able to access with my code. Any reason why?

```
var error: Unmanaged<CFError>?
addressBook = ABAddressBookCreateWithOptions(nil, &error).takeRetainedValue()


   if let people = ABAddressBookCopyArrayOfAllPeopleInSourceWithSortOrdering(self.addressBook, nil, ABPersonSortOrdering(kABPersonSortByFirstName)).takeRetainedValue() as? NSArray {
        for record in people {
            //var contactPerson: ABRecordRef = record
            var contactName: String = ABRecordCopyCompositeName(record).takeRetainedValue() as String


            var number = ""

            var phones: ABMultiValueRef = ABRecordCopyValue(record, kABPersonPhoneProperty).takeRetainedValue()

            for j in 0..<ABMultiValueGetCount(phones) {
                number = ABMultiValueCopyValueAtIndex(phones, j).takeRetainedValue() as! String
                break
            }

            if (number != "") {
                var newPerson = personInfo(name: contactName, number: number)
                allContacts.append(newPerson)
            }


           self.tableView.reloadData()
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

James Richards Please Use the Contacts frame work instead of using address book.

First you shoud add Contacts framework through Build Phases->Link Binary with Libraries->add(click +)->choose contacts framework

```
import Contacts
```

Then

```
let status = CNContactStore.authorizationStatusForEntityType(.Contacts)
if status == .Denied || status == .Restricted {
        // user previously denied, so tell them to fix that in settings
        return
}

// open it

let store = CNContactStore()
store.requestAccessForEntityType(.Contacts) { granted, error in
        guard granted else {
            dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) {
                // user didn't grant authorization, so tell them to fix that in settings
                print(error)
            }
            return
}

// get the contacts

var contacts = [CNContact]()
let request = CNContactFetchRequest(keysToFetch:[CNContactIdentifierKey, CNContactFormatter.descriptorForRequiredKeysForStyle(.FullName)])
   do {
      try store.enumerateContactsWithFetchRequest(request) { contact, stop in
                contacts.append(contact)
         }
   } 
   catch {
            print(error)
         }

        // do something with the contacts array (e.g. print the names)

        let formatter = CNContactFormatter()
        formatter.style = .FullName
        for contact in contacts {
            print(formatter.stringFromContact(contact))
        }
 }
```

The Output Results

```
Optional("John Appleseed")
Optional("Kate Bell")
Optional("Anna Haro")
Optional("Daniel Higgins Jr.")
Optional("David Taylor")
Optional("Hank M. Zakroff")
```

[Link 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24852175/how-to-retrieve-address-book-contacts-with-swift)

[Apple Document](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/Contacts/Reference/CNContactStore_Class/index.html)

[Contacts](https://www.safaribooksonline.com/library/view/ios-9-swift/9781491936689/ch04.html)

Comment: Unfortunately I need to make the app compatible with iOS 8 as well